# A simple parser generator

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6, lexical-analysis

I need to parse simple DSLs in a few projects. Since I don't know BNF or other grammars, I figured an alternative would be to use a simple parser generator.

I'm looking for improvements to the lexer/parser in order to be able to use it to parse more complex languages in future projects while keeping a relatively simple interface to define a grammar.

Feedback to increase code quality would be highly appreciated.

I'd also like to know if I'm missing crucial features a lexer/parser would have to include.

If I'm doing anything inherently wrong or do use inappropriate techniques, that would be helpful to know as well.

I'll include a simple usage example at the beginning and post the code and snippet at the bottom. I think in that order it's easier to follow the code.

Here's an example of how to tokenize a basic arithmetic expression like `1+2+3*4*5*6+3`;

```javascript
const tokenDefinitions = [
    TokenFactory({type:'Whitespace', ignore: true}).while(/^\s+$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Integer'}).start(/-|\d/).next(/^\d$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Paren'}).start(/^[()]$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Addition'}, true).start(/^\+|-$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Multiplication'}, true).start(/^\*|\\$/),
];

const src = '1 + 2 + 3 * 4 * 5'
const lexer = Lexer(tokenDefinitions);
const tokens = lexer(src).filter(t => !t.ignore);
```

Here's an example to parse the tokens to an AST.

```
const Any = new Driver('Any').match(_ => true);
const Number = new Driver('Number').match(type('Integer')).bind(0, 0);
const RParen = new Driver('RParen').match(value(')')).bind(100, 0);
const Expression = new Driver('Expression').match(value('(')).consumeRight().end(value(')')).bind(0, 99)
const MulOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Multiplication')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().bind(60,60)
const AddOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Addition')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().bind(50,50)

const nodeDefinitions = [
    MulOperator,
    AddOperator,
    Number,
    Expression,
    RParen,
];

const parse = Parser(nodeDefinitions);
const ast = parse(tokens);
```

<sub>This example uses left and right binding powers to define the precedence of the multiplication over addition. You can get the same result by using `.until`, but that feels kind of wrong.</sub>

```
const Any = new Driver('Any').match(_ => true);
const Number = new Driver('Number').match(type('Integer'));
const RParen = new Driver('RParen').match(value(')'));
const Expression = new Driver('Expression').match(value('(')).consumeRight().until(value(')')).end(value(')'))
const MulOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Multiplication')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().until(parentOr(type('Addition')))
const AddOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Addition')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().until(parent)
```

<sub>In this example, the multiplication operator consumes tokens until it encounters an addition token, or if inside an expression, a right parenthesis.</sub>

Both examples produce the following AST.

```javascript
[
  {
    children: [
      { children: [], token: { value: '1' }, id: 'Number' },
      {
        children: [
          { children: [], token: { value: '2' }, id: 'Number' },
          {
            children: [
              {
                children: [
                  { children: [], token: { value: '3' }, id: 'Number' },
                  {
                    children: [
                      {
                        children: [],
                        token: { value: '4' },
                        id: 'Number'
                      },
                      {
                        children: [
                          {
                            children: [],
                            token: { value: '5' },
                            id: 'Number'
                          },
                          {
                            children: [],
                            token: { value: '6' },
                            id: 'Number'
                          }
                        ],
                        token: { type: 'Multiplication', value: '*' },
                        id: 'Operator'
                      }
                    ],
                    token: { type: 'Multiplication', value: '*' },
                    id: 'Operator'
                  }
                ],
                token: { type: 'Multiplication', value: '*' },
                id: 'Operator'
              },
              { children: [], token: { value: '3' }, id: 'Number' }
            ],
            token: { type: 'Addition', value: '+' },
            id: 'Operator'
          }
        ],
        token: { type: 'Addition', value: '+' },
        id: 'Operator'
      }
    ],
    token: { type: 'Addition', value: '+' },
    id: 'Operator'
  }
]
```

<sub>You can flatten the recursive structure of the AST by changing the grammar of addition and multiplication tokens to repeatedly parse its RHS while its condition matches by using `.repeat`, or by using `.unfold` which recurses first and flattens the structure after parsing the node. This can reduce the size of the AST a lot.</sub>

```
[
  {
    children: [
      { children: [], token: { value: '1' }, id: 'Number' },
      { children: [], token: { value: '2' }, id: 'Number' },
      {
        children: [
          { children: [], token: { value: '3' }, id: 'Number' },
          { children: [], token: { value: '4' }, id: 'Number' },
          { children: [], token: { value: '5' }, id: 'Number' },
          { children: [], token: { value: '6' }, id: 'Number' }
        ],
        token: { type: 'Multiplication', value: '*' },
        id: 'Operator'
      },
      { children: [], token: { value: '3' }, id: 'Number' }
    ],
    token: { type: 'Addition', value: '+' },
    id: 'Operator'
  }
]
```

```
const AddOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Addition')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().until(parent).repeat()
```

Here's an example of how to interpret the AST.
<sub>It doesn't matter if the AST is flattened or not, all versions (bind/until, repeat/unfold) will be  interpreted correctly as the semantic doesn't change*</sub>

```
const operators = {
    '+': (a,b) => a+b,
    '-': (a,b) => a-b,
    '*': (a,b) => a*b,
    '/': (a,b) => a/b,
};

const hasId = id => token => token.id === id;
const tokenValue = node => node.token.value;

const NrBh = new Behaviour(hasId('Number'), n => +tokenValue(n))
const OpBh = new Behaviour(hasId('Operator'), (node, _eval) =>  node.children.map(c => _eval(c)).reduce(operators[tokenValue(node)]));
const ExprBh = new Behaviour(hasId('Expression'), (node, _eval) => _eval(node.rhs));

const behaviours = [NrBh, OpBh, ExprBh];
const res = Behaviour.eval(ast[0], behaviours); // 63
```

Here's the code for the lexer.

```
//Matcher.js

const setInstanceProp = (instance, key, value) => (instance[key] = value, instance);

/**
 * The Matcher defines multiple regular expressions or functions that are matched against a single character at different positions.
 */
class Matcher {
    constructor (transform) {
        /** Can be given a transform function that transforms the token value */
        if (typeof transform === 'function')
            this._transform = transform
    }

    /** Consumes a character once at the beginning.*/
    start (regExp) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_start', regExp)}
    /** Consumes a character each step*/
    next (regExp) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_next', regExp)}
    /** Consumes a character and terminates the current token*/
    end (regExp) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_end', regExp)}
    /** Consumes characters as long as the regExp matches */
    while (regExp) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_while', regExp)}

    /** Tests a regex or function against a character */
    _test (obj, char)  {
        if (typeof obj === 'function')
            return obj(char);
        if (obj instanceof RegExp)
            return obj.test(char);
        return false;
    }

    /** Tests a character and token against the defined regexes/functions. Can be given a hint to test a specific regex/fn */
    test (char, token = '', hint)  {
        if (hint === null) return false;
        if (hint) return this._test(hint, char)
        if (this._start && !token) return this._test(this._start, char);
        if (this._next)  return this._test(this._next, char);
        if (this._while) return this._test(this._while, token + char);
        
        return false;
    }

    /** Default transform behaviour. Returns the primitive token value */
    _transform (token) {
        return token;
    }

    /** Called by the tokenizer to transform the primitive token value to an object*/
    transform (token) {
        return this._transform(token);
    }
}

/** Creates a matcher that transforms the matched token into an object with a prototype that shares common information*/
const TokenFactory = (proto, assign) => new Matcher((value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object') return value
    if (assign)
        return Object.assign({}, proto, {value})
    return Object.assign(Object.create(proto), {value})
});

module.exports = {Matcher, TokenFactory};
```

```
//Lexer.js

const {Matcher} = require('./Matcher');

const Lexer = (def) =>  (src) => {
    return src.split('').reduce((acc, char, i, arr) => {
        let [token, lastMatcher, tokens] = acc;
        const {_end = null} = lastMatcher; let ret; 
        if (lastMatcher.test(char, token, _end)) {
            ret = [lastMatcher.transform(token+char), new Matcher, tokens];
        } else if (lastMatcher.test(char, token)) {
            ret = [token+char, lastMatcher,tokens];
        } else {
            const matcher = def.find(matcher => matcher.test(char));
            if (!matcher) throw new Error(`No matcher found for character '${char}'.`);
            token && tokens.push(lastMatcher.transform(token));
            ret = [char, matcher, tokens];
            lastMatcher = matcher;
        }

        if (i === arr.length - 1) {
            tokens.push(lastMatcher.transform(ret[0]));
            ret = tokens;
        }

        return ret;
    }, ['', new Matcher, []]);
}

module.exports = {Lexer};
```

Here's the code of the parser.

```
//Driver.js

class Driver {
    constructor (id, transform) {
        this.id = id;
        this._transform = transform;
        this.bind();
    };

    match (token) {
        this._match = token;
        return this;
    }
    consumeLeft (token) {
        this._consumeLeft = token;
        return this;
    }

    consumeRight (token = true, n = Infinity) {
        this._consumeRight = token;
        this.n = n;
        return this;
    }

    end (token) {
        this._end = token;
        return this;
    }

    unfold () {
        this._unfold = true;
        return this;
    }

    until (token, lookAhead = 0) {
        this._until = token;
        this._lookAhead = lookAhead;
        return this;
    }

    repeat (token) {
        this._repeat = true;
        return this;
    }

    test (token, nodes = []) {
        let ret;
        if (typeof this._match === 'function')
            ret = this._match(token);
        else if (this._match) {
            ret = token.type === this._match || token.value === this._match;
        }

        if (this._consumeLeft) {
            const lhs = nodes.slice().pop();
            ret = ret && lhs && (lhs.id === this._consumeLeft.id || this._consumeLeft.test(lhs.token));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    transform (node) {
        if (typeof this._transform === 'function')
            return {...this._transform(node), id: this.id};
        return {...node, id: this.id};
    }
    
    bind (l = 0, r = 0) {
        this.lbp = l;
        this.rbp = r;
        return this;
    }
}

module.exports = {Driver};
```

```
//Parser.js 

const Parser = nodeDefinitions => {
    const nodes = [];
    return function parse (tokens, parents = []) {
        if (tokens.length === 0)return [];

        const [parent, ...rest] = parents;
        let i=0;

        do {
            const token = tokens.shift();

            const node = {children:[]};
            const cur = nodeDefinitions.find (d => d.test(token, nodes));

            if (!cur) {
                throw new Error(`Unexpected token ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);
            }

            let next = tokens[0]
            const nextDriver = next && nodeDefinitions.find (d => d.test(next, nodes));
            
            if (parent && nextDriver && parent.rbp < nextDriver.lbp) {
                tokens.unshift(token);
                break;
            }
            
            next = parent && (parent._lookAhead==0?token:tokens[parent._lookAhead - 1]);
            if (parent && parent._until && next && parent._until(next, parents, nodes)) {
                tokens.unshift(token);
                break;
            }       

            if (cur._consumeLeft) {
                const lhs = nodes.pop();
                if (!cur.test(token, [lhs]))
                    throw new Error(`Expected token ${cur._consumeLeft._match} but found ${lhs.token.type} instead. ${cur.name}`)
                node.children.push(lhs);
            }

            if (cur._consumeRight) {
                let repeat = false;
                do {
                    parse(tokens, [cur, ...parents]);
                    const rhs = nodes.shift();
                    node.children.push(rhs);
                    if (tokens[0] && cur.test(tokens[0], [node.children[0]])) {
                        tokens.shift();
                        repeat = true;
                    } else {
                        repeat = false;
                    }
                } while (repeat);
            }
            
            node.token = token;

            if (cur._unfold) {
                const rhs = node.children.slice(-1)[0];
                const un = rhs.children;
                if (node.token.value === rhs.token.value) {
                    node.children = [node.children[0], ...un];
                }
            } 

            if (cur._end && cur._end(tokens[0] || {}, cur, nodes)) {
                node.end = tokens.shift();
            }

            nodes.push(cur.transform(node));

            if (parent && ++i === parent.n) break;
        } while (tokens.length);

        return nodes;
    }
}

module.exports = {Parser};
```

Here's the code for the interpreter.

```
//Behaviour.js

class Behaviour {
    static eval (ast, behaviours) {
        const node = ast;
        const beh  = behaviours.find(b => b.testFn(ast)); 
        if (!beh)
            throw new Error(`No behaviour found for node ${JSON.stringify(node)}`)
        return beh.evalFn(node, (node, _behaviours = behaviours) => {
            const val = Behaviour.eval(node, _behaviours)
            return val;
        });
    }
    constructor (testFn, evalFn) {
        this.testFn = testFn;
        this.evalFn = evalFn;
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle to run the example.

```js
const tokenDefinitions = [
    TokenFactory({type:'Whitespace', ignore: true}).while(/^\s+$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Integer'}).start(/-|\d/).next(/^\d$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Paren'}).start(/^[()]$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Addition'}, true).start(/^\+|-$/),
    TokenFactory({type:'Multiplication'}, true).start(/^\*|\\$/),
];

const src = '1 + 2 + 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 + 3'
console.log ('Source', src);

const lexer = Lexer(tokenDefinitions);
const tokens = lexer(src).filter(t => !t.ignore);

console.log("Tokens", tokens);

const type = type => token => token.type === type;
const value = value => token => token.value === value;
const parent =  (token, parents, nodes) => parents[1] && parents[1]._until(token, parents.slice(1), nodes) ;
const or = (...fns) => (token, parents, nodes) => fns.reduce((a, fn) => a || fn(token, parents, nodes), false);
const and = (...fns) => (token, parents, nodes) => fns.reduce((a, fn) => a && fn(token, parents, nodes), true);
const parentOr = fn => or(parent, fn);
const keyword = token => type('Identifier')(token) && keywords.some(k => value(k)(token));

// const Any = new Driver('Any').match(_ => true);
// const Number = new Driver('Number').match(type('Integer')).bind(0, 0);
// const RParen = new Driver('RParen').match(value(')')).bind(100, 0);
// const Expression = new Driver('Expression').match(value('(')).consumeRight().end(value(')')).bind(0, 99)
// const MulOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Multiplication')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().bind(60,60)
// const AddOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Addition')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().bind(50,50)

const Any = new Driver('Any').match(_ => true);
const Number = new Driver('Number').match(type('Integer'));
const RParen = new Driver('RParen').match(value(')'));
const Expression = new Driver('Expression').match(value('(')).consumeRight().until(value(')')).end(value(')'))
const MulOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Multiplication')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().until(or(parent,type('Multiplication'),type('Addition'))).repeat()
const AddOperator = new Driver('Operator').match(type('Addition')).consumeLeft(Any).consumeRight().until(parentOr(type('Addition'))).repeat();

const nodeDefinitions = [
    MulOperator,
    AddOperator,
    Number,
    Expression,
    RParen,
];

const parse = Parser(nodeDefinitions);
const ast = parse(tokens);

console.log("AST", ast);

const operators = {
    '+': (a,b) => a+b,
    '-': (a,b) => a-b,
    '*': (a,b) => a*b,
    '/': (a,b) => a/b,
};

const hasId = id => token => token.id === id;
const tokenValue = node => node.token.value;

const NrBh = new Behaviour(hasId('Number'), n => +tokenValue(n))
const OpBh = new Behaviour(hasId('Operator'), (node, _eval) =>  node.children.map(c => _eval(c)).reduce(operators[tokenValue(node)]));
const ExprBh = new Behaviour(hasId('Expression'), (node, _eval) => _eval(node.rhs));

const behaviours = [NrBh, OpBh, ExprBh];
const res = Behaviour.eval(ast[0], behaviours);

console.log ("Result", res)
```

```html
<script>
const setInstanceProp = (instance, key, value) => (instance[key] = value, instance);

class Matcher {
    constructor (transform) {
        if (typeof transform === 'function')
            this._transform = transform
    }

    start (r) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_start', r)}
    next (r) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_next', r)}
    end (r) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_end', r)}
    while (r) {return setInstanceProp(this, '_while', r)}

    _test (obj, char)  {
        if (typeof obj === 'function')
            return obj(char);
        if (obj instanceof RegExp)
            return obj.test(char);
        return false;
    }

    test (char, token = '', hint)  {
        if (hint === null) return false;
        if (hint) return this._test(hint, char)
        if (this._start && !token) return this._test(this._start, char);
        if (this._next)  return this._test(this._next, char);
        if (this._while) return this._test(this._while, token + char);
        
        return false;
    }

    _transform (token) {
        return token;
    }

    transform (token) {
        return this._transform(token);
    }
}

const TokenFactory = (proto, assign) => new Matcher((value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object') return value
    if (assign)
        return Object.assign({}, proto, {value})
    return Object.assign(Object.create(proto), {value})
});

const Lexer = (def) =>  (src) => {
    return src.split('').reduce((acc, char, i, arr) => {
        let [token, lastMatcher, tokens] = acc;
        const {_end = null} = lastMatcher; let ret; 
        if (lastMatcher.test(char, token, _end)) {
            ret = [lastMatcher.transform(token+char), new Matcher, tokens];
        } else if (lastMatcher.test(char, token)) {
            ret = [token+char, lastMatcher,tokens];
        } else {
            const matcher = def.find(matcher => matcher.test(char));
            if (!matcher) throw new Error(`No matcher found for character '${char}'.`);
            token && tokens.push(lastMatcher.transform(token));
            ret = [char, matcher, tokens];
            lastMatcher = matcher;
        }

        if (i === arr.length - 1) {
            tokens.push(lastMatcher.transform(ret[0]));
            ret = tokens;
        }

        return ret;
    }, ['', new Matcher, []]);
}

class Driver {
    constructor (id, transform) {
        this.id = id;
        this._transform = transform;
        this.bind();
    };

    match (token) {
        this._match = token;
        return this;
    }
    consumeLeft (token) {
        this._consumeLeft = token;
        return this;
    }

    consumeRight (token = true, n = Infinity) {
        this._consumeRight = token;
        this.n = n;
        return this;
    }

    end (token) {
        this._end = token;
        return this;
    }

    unfold () {
        this._unfold = true;
        return this;
    }

    until (token, lookAhead = 0) {
        this._until = token;
        this._lookAhead = lookAhead;
        return this;
    }

    repeat (token) {
        this._repeat = true;
        return this;
    }

    test (token, nodes = []) {
        let ret;
        if (typeof this._match === 'function')
            ret = this._match(token);
        else if (this._match) {
            ret = token.type === this._match || token.value === this._match;
        }

        if (this._consumeLeft) {
            const lhs = nodes.slice().pop();
            ret = ret && lhs && (lhs.id === this._consumeLeft.id || this._consumeLeft.test(lhs.token));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    transform (node) {
        if (typeof this._transform === 'function')
            return {...this._transform(node), id: this.id};
        return {...node, id: this.id};
    }
    
    bind (l = 0, r = 0) {
        this.lbp = l;
        this.rbp = r;
        return this;
    }
}

const Parser = nodeDefinitions => {
    const nodes = [];
    return function parse (tokens, parents = []) {
        if (tokens.length === 0)return [];

        const [parent, ...rest] = parents;
        let i=0;

        do {
            const token = tokens.shift();

            const node = {children:[]};
            const cur = nodeDefinitions.find (d => d.test(token, nodes));

            if (!cur) {
                throw new Error(`Unexpected token ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);
            }

            let next = tokens[0]
            const nextDriver = next && nodeDefinitions.find (d => d.test(next, nodes));
            
            if (parent && nextDriver && parent.rbp < nextDriver.lbp) {
                tokens.unshift(token);
                break;
            }
            
            next = parent && (parent._lookAhead==0?token:tokens[parent._lookAhead - 1]);
            if (parent && parent._until && next && parent._until(next, parents, nodes)) {
                tokens.unshift(token);
                break;
            }       

            if (cur._consumeLeft) {
                const lhs = nodes.pop();
                if (!cur.test(token, [lhs]))
                    throw new Error(`Expected token ${cur._consumeLeft._match} but found ${lhs.token.type} instead. ${cur.name}`)
                node.children.push(lhs);
            }

            if (cur._consumeRight) {
                let repeat = false;
                do {
                    parse(tokens, [cur, ...parents]);
                    const rhs = nodes.shift();
                    node.children.push(rhs);
                    if (tokens[0] && cur.test(tokens[0], [node.children[0]])) {
                        tokens.shift();
                        repeat = true;
                    } else {
                        repeat = false;
                    }
                } while (repeat);
            }
            
            node.token = token;

            if (cur._unfold) {
                const rhs = node.children.slice(-1)[0];
                const un = rhs.children;
                if (node.token.value === rhs.token.value) {
                    node.children = [node.children[0], ...un];
                }
            } 

            if (cur._end && cur._end(tokens[0] || {}, cur, nodes)) {
                node.end = tokens.shift();
            }

            nodes.push(cur.transform(node));

            if (parent && ++i === parent.n) break;
        } while (tokens.length);

        return nodes;
    }
}

class Behaviour {
    static eval (ast, behaviours) {
        const node = ast;
        const beh  = behaviours.find(b => b.testFn(ast)); 
        if (!beh)
            throw new Error(`No behaviour found for node ${JSON.stringify(node)}`)
        return beh.evalFn(node, (node, _behaviours = behaviours) => {
            const val = Behaviour.eval(node, _behaviours)
            return val;
        });
    }
    constructor (testFn, evalFn) {
        this.testFn = testFn;
        this.evalFn = evalFn;
    }
}
</script>
```

---

Edit:

A few thoughts from my side. I don't really like prefixing methods or properties with a `_`. I think I can move the regular expression into an own object as they aren't tied to the instance. I think I can get rid of the `_transform` method by overriding `transform` in the constructor. I just thought that storing a function in a property that gets called by a class method is convenient since you could use it to validate input. If there's a cleaner way of doing this, that would be nice. I could use a `Map` store the function, then I wouldn't have to expose a `_transform` property.

I think that the binding powers should be changed to compare the current token against the next token. Currently, they work as follows. Given the source `1 + 2 * 3` and binding powers *50/50, 60/60* for the tokens *+* and *, the + token will compete with the * token over the *2* token. I thought that's easier to grasp, but it turns out that you can't use it to break out of the current parsing step, without using `until`. Which is a likely need. f.e. using `)` to designate the end of an expression. This only works if I compare the binding powers of two adjacent tokens.

Comment: My biggest feedback: add documentation to the lexer and parser! Writing your own parser generator is NOT more readable and maintainable than writing a custom parser, unless you write very clearly what exactly each piece is supposed to do, and it is foolproof.

Answer (score 4):

#### Disclaimer: Not a Code Reviewer

Your code looks pretty good! Just briefly commenting:

- My guess is that maybe you might want to design some low-complexity algorithms to do the parsing (if not using an already developed parser – which would have been my first choice – browsing through GitHub), rather than using operational-intensive string manipulations with [fledgling regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764247/why-are-regular-expressions-so-controversial).
- Here is just an example using stack:

```js
const parser = function(s) {

    if (s.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }


    let stack = [];
    let operation = "+";

    for (let index = 0, num = 0; index <= s.length; ++index) {
        if (s[index] === ' ') {
            continue;
        }


        if (s[index] >= '0' && s[index] <= '9') {
            num *= 10;
            num += parseInt(s[index]);
            continue;
        }

        if (operation === '+') {
            stack.push(num);

        } else if (operation === '-') {
            stack.push(-num);

        } else if (operation === '*') {
            stack.push(stack.pop() * num);

        } else if (operation === '/') {
            stack.push(Math.trunc(stack.pop() / num));
        }

        operation = s[index];
        num = 0;
    }

    return stack.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
};


console.log(parser("  1 + 2 + 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 + 3  "));
```

#### Happy Coding!! ( ˆ_ˆ )

---

#### Reference

- [Prefix calculator using stack in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745538/prefix-calculator-using-stack-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t done much thinking about lexers since I was a university student 14 years ago and was in a compilers class.  I have been working with Javascript since then.

Overall the code looks well-written. Variables are declared well using `const` and `let` appropriately. Many other ES6 features appear to be applied appropriately. Strict comparisons are utilized to avoid needless type coercions.

I agree with removing the underscores from method and property names. This would follow recommendations of popular style guides- e.g. [AirBNB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--leading-underscore).

I see these lines of code in the `Parser` function `parse()`

> ```
> let repeat = false;
> do {
>     parse(tokens, [cur, ...parents]);
>     const rhs = nodes.shift();
>     node.children.push(rhs);
>     if (tokens[0] && cur.test(tokens[0], [node.children[0]])) {
>         tokens.shift();
>         repeat = true;
>     } else {
>         repeat = false;
>     }
> } while (repeat);
> ```

The `do` loop could be changed to a `for` loop, and variable `rhs` is only used once after assignment so it doesn’t need to be stored.

```
for (let repeat = true; repeat; ) {
    parse(tokens, [cur, ...parents]);
    node.children.push(nodes.shift());
    if (tokens[0] && cur.test(tokens[0], [node.children[0]])) {
        tokens.shift();
        repeat = true;
    } else {
        repeat = false;
    }
}
```